# Vim rewrite whole file on save?

Tags: save

I opened a large file, didn't make a modification, and pressed `:w`. Then Vim was frozen for a while. Was it simply rewriting the whole file? Is it possible to make it understand that there was no change so that it could just quit? To generalize a little bit, is it possible to let it not rewrite the whole file if I only modified a small part of it?

Comment: I think `:exit` (`:x`) will do what you want, but only if you also want to quit.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah, and if you modify one byte, `:x` would freeze.

Comment: Well sure. There were changes.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `:write` you should use `:update`.  According to vim's help:

```
                            *:up* *:update*
:[range]up[date][!] [++opt] [>>] [file]
            Like ":write", but only write when the buffer has been
            modified.  {not in Vi}
```

As stated, this will only write out the file to disk if there have been modifications known to vim.  You would use `:write` instead if, for example, you have changed or corrupted the file on disk and would like to write vim's buffer contents again.

Comment: Sounds better than `:x`. But what if I modified a byte but don't want Vim completely rewrite the whole file?

Answer (score 4):

I did a short check with `strace` on Linux. I edit `README.md` and add one character to the last line.

Here is the relevant part:

```
01: stat("README.md", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5986, ...}) = 0
02: stat("README.md~", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5988, ...}) = 0
03: unlink("README.md~")                    = 0
04: rename("README.md", "README.md~")       = 0
05: open("README.md", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644) = 3
06: ftruncate(3, 0)                         = 0
07: write(3, "![Vim Logo](https://github.com/v"..., 5987) = 5987
08: fsync(3)                                = 0
09: stat("README.md", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5987, ...}) = 0
10: stat("README.md", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5987, ...}) = 0
11: fchmod(3, 0100644)                      = 0
12: close(3)                                = 0
```

The lines 02-04 show how the backup file is created. Here the original file is moved to `README.md~` (a already existing `README.md~` is deleted in in line 03).

Then the new file `README.md` is written line 05-12. In line 06 the call to `ftruncate` truncates the file to zero (irrelevant here, as this is a new file) and then the complete content is written (5987 byte).

Note that depending on the option `backupcopy`, the backup file `README.md~` might be written, instead of just renaming `README.md` to `README.md~`.

Here with `set nobackup`:

```
01: open("README.md", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644) = 3
02: ftruncate(3, 0)                         = 0
03: write(3, "![Vim Logo](https://github.com/v"..., 5987) = 5987
04: fsync(3)                                = 0
05: stat("README.md", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5987, ...}) = 0
06: stat("README.md", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5987, ...}) = 0
07: fchmod(3, 0100644)                      = 0
08: close(3)                                = 0
```

Here no backup file is created, but also the file `README.md` is first truncated to size zero and then the complete content is written (5987  byte).

My conclusion: Vim always writes the entire file.

I'm not aware that there is any option to just write changed parts. Also this would be not trivial to implement.